# Puppeteer - Click on ad

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm doing some freelance work for a guy who wants information on the ads on his website. I need to click on the ad with Puppeteer and get the resulting page url.

Here's what I tried.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://example.com/page/ad', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  await page.click('#aw0')
})();
```

It keeps returning `Error: No node found for selector: #aw0`

Comment: Maybe there is no node for the selector `#aw0` are you seeing the ad displayed in chrome?

Comment: @Luca the ad shows up in Chrome, and I can go to dev tools and use document.getElementById.href and it works just fine.

Comment: can you confirm if the element is inside the same frame or some inner iframe?
possibly from console, you are entering the inner frame when you inspect and enter console

Comment: That's probably it. It's in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on ads definitely works, however you will need to tweak every single ad section differently and beware of the consequences.

## Disclaimer

Read and use the content of the answer at your own risk,

- Beware that clicking on ad automatically might result in banning from the ad network since there are many ways to know if the click was from actual user or not.
- This have been done for many years and ended up badly. The below is to show how it works, but again, your/clients account will be banned for sure because if I were the ad network I'd avoid such easy method to cheat.
- Some ads will trigger popups, so beware of ghost chrome processes too.
- The cost of running the puppeteer and click ad might be actually bigger than doing marketing and such stuff to the website.

## Overview

Consider this page with this simple ad, if you try to inspect, you will see iframe, but see further, it's an iframe inside iframe and that varies greatly between adservices and target website.

[image]

## Clicking element within frame, within frame...?

As discussed [here on the issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/618#issuecomment-338392382), So far we could do this to click something within frame.

```
await page.goto('https://example.com');
const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'someIframe');
const button = await frame.$('button');
button.click();
```

Now, if we want to click this particular element, what can be done? The name is not there, the id is random. Going to actual ad page will reveal the iframe, but again check above disclaimer,

If you see, the main iframe src says, `/ads/adprotect300.aspx`, so we can open it and click on the element there. We also see the iframe has a name starting with `mdns`. Taking all research in mind, we can prepare a code like this,

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://example.com/ads/adprotect300.aspx', {waituntil: "networkidle0"});
await page.waitFor('iframe');
await page.waitFor(4000); // artificial wait for randomness
const frame = await page.frames().find(f=>f.name().includes('mdns'));
const ad = await frame.$('div > a');
ad.click();
```

In this website, it opened a new tab, as stated before, it clicked and now we have to do is grab the links for all open tabs, so if it has any popups or redirects on new tab, it will be grabbed.

```
await page.waitFor(2000);
const pages = await browser.pages()
console.log(pages.map(page=>page.url()))
```

There are better ways to wait for the navigation and all, but I am just showing what can be done. The result,

```
[ 'chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html',
  'http://example.com/ads/adprotect300.aspx',
  'https://adwebsite/activity/htb/candy/pc?ref=93454&i=704ea49d-7b0b-4c05-b4d0-f0225ecc7154&h=12700290a03e232a14fa0f1cf35e27a346d91f6e&c=878146837666' ]
```

Let me remind you once again, this is clearly illegal and the accounts might be put on risk. Use your head at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use waitFor to make sure that the specific selector is available in the DOM
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args

Comment: I tried that and it just hangs. Could it be because the ad is generated in JS?

Comment: It hangs/waits (and ends with a timeOut) if the selector is not available.

Comment: @RyanKnutson, waitFor is used to wait for elements added dynamically with JS

Comment: can you confirm if the element is inside the same frame or some inner iframe? possibly from console, you are entering the inner frame when you inspect and enter console